# Merging changes to my local repo without overwriting my changes

Tags: git, github, github-actions, git-pull

I would just like to seek some help. I've been browsing over stackoverflow and google but somehow cannot find an answer for this. I am collaborating with someone and he is the owner of the remote repo in Github. I forked his repo and then cloned it to my local repo. I started doing my own changes on my local repo, but my question is, if he updates a his side of the repo, how do I update my side without my changes being overwritten?

I'm not sure which command I should use to safely do this. Should I just pull his changes and re-paste the changes I've made? Sorry if this is a stupid question, I am new to collaborating in Github. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Work on a branch? That way, updating from upstream doesn't touch your code unless you decide to merge it in.

Comment: Instead of searching around the internet for answers, please start with a good enough Git book. People usually follow standardized workflows (such as creating feature branches) and then everything else works in well known ways, https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows It's not hard to find more resources on such.

Comment: Hey matt, yes. But my question was, if let's say he updates the repo and I want to pull the changes he made, how do I pull his code from github without my code being overwritten as well as the changes.

Comment: @LexLi I'll try getting my hands on one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I started doing my own changes on my local repo, but my question is, if he updates a his side of the repo, how do I update my side without my changes being overwritten?

The sequence of commands would be:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/original/repository
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                          replace it with the "someone/repo" name
```

Then when you want to check if your code works on top of their updated code (assuming said code was pushed on their `main` branch):

```bash
git fetch upstream

# replay your current branch work on top of their branch
git rebase upstream/main
# check everything work
...

# Then update your own fork
git push --force
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try this out when I get home.